# Django rest_framework with custom User model - duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I start to learn django (rest_framework) and build an app. I created a custom user model and manager, below the code:

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=255, unique=False, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(_('mobile'),max_length=255, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/thumbnail/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    @property
    def picture_preview(self):
        if self.picture:
            return mark_safe('<img src="{}" width="300" height="300" />'.format(self.picture.url))
        return ""

    objects = CustomUserManager()
```

I have also customize the view for the admin..and everything work fine.

Now when I register a new user from the admin and for instance I put two time the same email I receive this error message : **User with this Email address already exists.**

But if I register a new user using postman to call the api I receive the error below:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "accounts_customuser_email_key" 
DETAIL:  Key (email)=(mario@mario.it) already exists.
```

Below the Serializer class

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def validate(self, attrs):
        # Check if user exist
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        # if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        #     raise serializers.ValidationError(
        #         'User with this Email address already exists.')

        # Validate password
        errors = dict()
        user = CustomUser(**attrs)
        password = attrs.get('password', '')
        try:
            # validate the password and catch the exception
            validators.validate_password(password=password, user=user)

        # the exception raised here is different than serializers.ValidationError
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors['password'] = list(e.messages)

        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return CustomUser.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

In the validator I commented the code that check if user is already register this because I'm expecting that django should know if email is already register without extra code since in the admin it work without problem.

and the view class:

```
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializers_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializers_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        user_data = serializer.data
        return Response(user_data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

My question is am I doing something wrong? Did I missed somthing?

Thank you all...any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you create user with same email django checks and raises IntegrityError. You have to catch this exception and return the response. Also its better you should do it in view part not in serializer validate method as the job of serializer's validate method is to only check if the given inputs are correct. so your view should look something like this.

```
class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializers_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializers_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        try:
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                email=serializer.data.get("email"),
                password=request.data.get("password"),
            )
        except IntegrityError:
            return Response("Email already exists.",
                status=status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE,
            )
        response = jwt_response_payload_handler(user.get_jwt_token(), user, request) #  some payload handler, for user information
        return Response(response, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```